# what's the difference between a CPP/CLI assembly and a CS/VB assembly?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I do know some "basic" differences but there are still some questions in my mind:

- What's their difference in performance at runtime? //This I really wanna know.
- Why can't you build a MSIL assembly using C++/CLI?
- What's the PE code (Not the .NET's PEKind) of a MSIL/CIL assembly? (C++/CLI assemblies have the same PE Code than unmanaged binaries, right?)

Any further knowledge/answers are appreciated.

Comment: By the way, don't tell my project manager I asked this :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C++/CLI assembly can contain native code, which has the *potential* to be more performant than managed code. However, the transitions between native and managed code (usually when calling into a native class, or a native API call) involves some automatically-generated marshalling and boxing, which can really suck up some cycles.

As to your second question, you can. Take a look at [/clr:pure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s(VS.80).aspx).

Managed and mixed-mode assemblies are both DLLs, but they have extended [.NET metadata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#.NET.2C_metadata.2C_and_the_PE_format). Pure MSIL assemblies just don't have a native interface (try `dumpbin /exports C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5.dll`, then `ildasm` the same file).